# how to add and remove number without duplicate in the state object inside the array in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

The below code which i'm using to add the data in the state the code is

```
 this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      frequency: {
        ...state.frequency,
        days: [...state.frequency.days, parseInt(val)],
      },
    }));
```

my State is Given Below

```
this.state = {
      frequency: {
        days: [],
      },}
```

im adding numeric value from 1 to 30 but when i try to add same number it adds to the array i should not add it again
please give me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before updating the state perform an evaluation like then assign the days

```
let tempDays = this.state.frequency.days.includes(parseInt(val)) ? [...this.state.frequency.days] : [...this.state.frequency.days, parseInt(val)]

 this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      frequency: {
        ...state.frequency,
        days: tempDays ,
      },
    }));
```

for deletion

```
let tempDays = this.state.frequency.days.filter( day => day !== parseInt(val))

     this.setState((state) => ({
          ...state,
          frequency: {
            ...state.frequency,
            days: [...tempDays] ,
          },
        }));
```

Comment: And I have to remove the number using delete functionality ? is that possible right?

i list out each numbers with delete button .. when i click delete i have to remove the data from the array..

Answer (score 1):

You can check if value already exists in the array or not if it is, do not update state, as simple as that!

```
const numVal = parseInt(val);
if (this.state.frequency.days.indexOf(numVal) > -1) {
  return;
}

this.setState((state) => ({
  ...state,
  frequency: {
     ...state.frequency,
     days: [...state.frequency.days, numVal],
   },
}));
```

Comment: And I have to remove the number using delete functionality ? is that possible right?

i list out each numbers with delete button .. when i click delete i have to remove the data from the array..

Comment: You can use filter function to create new array without any number and update state.

Answer (score 0):

first, you can check the array with include the method of array an then pass data into the array.
example

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 if(!x.include(your_number)){
  x.push(your_number) 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

And I have to remove the number using delete functionality ? is that possible right?

i list out each numbers with delete button .. when i click delete i have to remove the data from the array..